# Decomposition of 3D FFT using 1D FFT in dimension z

Tags: matlab, fft

I have a 3D matrix:

```
A = [5 7 8; 0 1 9; 4 3 6];
A(:,:,2) = [1 0 4; 3 5 6; 9 8 7]
```

I want to apply a 3D FFT in this matrix using decomposition of 1D FFT. I read that it I should apply 1D FFT in each dimension.

How can I do this?

For x and y, I do this:

```
for k=0:2
    y1 = A(:,k+1,:);
    A(:,k+1,:) = fft(y1);
end

for k=0:2
    y2 = A(k+1,:,:);
    A(k+1,:,:) = fft(y2);
end
```

For the dimension z, I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The [`fft`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html) function accepts a third input specifiying dimension, and is vectorized with respect to the other dimensions. So you can simply use:

```
result = fft(fft(fft(A, [], 1), [], 2), [], 3);
```

Comment: thanks for your reponse your method can help me but I want to using the boucle for in x and y and z. I how can I do this in z?

Comment: @kais: What is "the boucle"? Do you mean loop?

Comment: Yes I mean loop.I want to do the fft also in z diemnsion using loop same of the other x and y.please help me

Answer (score 0):

**First**, your loops should look like this:

```
for k=1:size(A,2)
    y = A(:,k,:);
    A(:,k,:) = fft(y);
end
```

**Second**, the loop above is identical to (as @Luis Mendo said in his answer):

```
A = fft(A,[],2);
```

There is no need to write a loop at all.

**Third**, to compute the 1D FFT along the 3rd dimension, you use:

```
fft(A,[],3);
```

You *could* write this as a loop (just to answer your explicit question, I don't recommend you do this):

```
for k=1:size(A,3)
    y = A(:,:,k);
    A(:,:,k) = fft(y);
end
```

If, for some reason, that doesn't work in your version of MATLAB because of the shape of `y`, you can reshape `y` to be a column vector:

```
... fft(y(:));
```

**Finally**, to compute the 3D FFT using 1D decompositions, you can simply write

```
A = fftn(A);
```

This follows the exact same process you are trying to implement, except it does it much faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Please have you any idea how to parallelize the 3D FFT in to p processeurs

Comment: MATLAB uses all cores at its disposal. If you have more than one core on your computer, they’ll all be used with `fft` or or `fft3` applied to a multi-dimensional array (but probably not with `fft` applied to a vector`, as that is more difficult to parallelize).